# Page loader timedout in chrome . but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, loader

I have included a loader and tried hide operation and timeout operation, which works with chrome ,but not with firefox. Firefox , the loader keep on loading and never ends.

HTML:

```
 <div id="loading">
      <img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#loading {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   position: fixed;
   display: block;
   opacity: 0.7;
   background-color: #fff;
   z-index: 99;
   text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 240px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Included script before closing body tag.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         $(window).load(function() {
         $('#loading').hide();
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: How is this AngularJS related?

Comment: The load event has been removed from jQuery. https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: it works with chrome , but not firefox

Comment: Have you opened the link? There it says "Caveats of the load event when used with images: [...] It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser"

Comment: so any other solution available for this page loader

Answer (score 0):

Use **.on** event

```
 $( window ).on( "load", function() { 
     //Code on load
     $('#loading').hide();
 }
```

https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: when I tried this , both of them not working chrome and firefix